# ul dropdown moves next div and hr

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

divs look like this:
[divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpTd5.png)

if I open dropdown - all elements move for 120px:

[divs if dropdown is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HG42.png)

Dropdown is maden with this html:

```
  <div class="cart__item_description_col">
                    <h5>Срок аренды</h5>
                <div>
                    <label class="custom-select">
                    <select name="sample" id="" class="select" style="border-radius: 6px; padding: 10px; padding-right:40px;">
                      <option value="1">1 месяц</option>
                      <option value="3">3 месяца</option>
                      <option value="6">6 месяцев</option>
                    </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                  </div>
```

And JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select').forEach(setupSelector);

function setupSelector(selector) {
    selector.addEventListener('change', e => {
        console.log('changed', e.target.value)
    })

    selector.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
        if(window.innerWidth >= 420) {// override look for non mobile
            e.preventDefault();

            const select = selector.children[0];
            const dropDown = document.createElement('div');
            dropDown.className = "UlDiv";
            const dropDownUl = document.createElement('ul');
            dropDownUl.className = "selector-options";

            [...select.children].forEach(option => {
                const dropDownOption = document.createElement('li');
                dropDownOption.textContent = option.textContent;

                dropDownOption.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    select.value = option.value;
                    selector.value = option.value;
                    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
                    selector.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
                    dropDown.remove();
                });

                dropDown.appendChild(dropDownUl);
                dropDownUl.appendChild(dropDownOption);
            });

            selector.appendChild(dropDown);

            // handle click out
            document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                if(!selector.contains(e.target)) {
                    dropDown.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });



}
```

Html when JS is executed:

```
<select name="sample" id="" class="select" style="border-radius: 6px; padding: 10px; padding-right:40px;">
                      <option value="1">1 месяц</option>
                      <option value="3">3 месяца</option>
                      <option value="6">6 месяцев</option>
                    </select>
<div class="UlDiv"><ul class="selector-options"><li>1 месяц</li><li>3 месяца</li><li>6 месяцев</li></ul></div>
```

It happened when I added style to look `ul` better:

```
.UlDiv{
    margin-top:120px;
}
```

How can I save margin for ul and make another elements unmovable so `ul` will be over others?

Comment: This happens because you add `div` elements to the document flow. You can try giving them `position:relative` to position them "above" the document.